# MATLAB - Error creating maxmaci64 from jpeg_write.c

Tags: matlab, compilation, macos-catalina, mex, libjpeg

I had problems making mexmaci64 files using Mex from both jpeg_read.c and jpeg_write.c from jpeg toolbox. I asked my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64786549/matlab-error-compiling-jpeg-read-c-to-create-mexmaci64-file) and the problem for jpeg_read solved.
but I still have a different error when I compile jpeg_write.c.
everything is the same and I didn't change any path or anything.
I don't understand why Matlab console returns this error.
Is this familiar to anybody? please let me know.

```cs
>> mex -compatibleArrayDims -I/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/9d/include jpeg_write.c -L/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/9d/lib -ljpeg
Building with 'Xcode with Clang'.
Error using mex
/Users/folder/jpeg_toolbox/jpeg_write.c:56:10: fatal error: 'jpegint.h' file not found
#include <jpegint.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Do you have the 'jpegint.h' file anywhere on your system? Is it part of the package you downloaded?

Comment: No, I searched the file name and it didn't exist anywhere. I don't know what library should I install to have that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off:

By pointing at the `/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/<version>/include` location of the `jpeg` or other libraries, you're dependent on the specific version that is currently installed. You probably want to use `/usr/local/opt/jpeg/include/` etc instead. `/usr/local/opt` is where Homebrew exposes its non-versioned presentations of its installed package contents.

So:

```
mex -compatibleArrayDims -I/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/9d/include ...
```

This is pointing at the `jpeg` library. Does the `jpeg` library supply `jpegint.h`?

```
$ ls /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/9d/include/
jconfig.h  jerror.h  jmorecfg.h  jpeglib.h
```

Nope. So that's why it's not found. So you have to figure out where you can actually get `jpegint.h` from. Hit Google and consult your documentation to figure out what library you're actually trying to pull `jpegint.h` from, and pull that in, too, with the appropriate `-I`, `-L`, and `-l` flags.

If you think you have it already installed, you can use `find /usr/local/Cellar -name jpegint.h` to look for it. I found it in the `gdcm` package.

```
[~] $ find /usr/local/Cellar -name jpegint.h
/usr/local/Cellar/gdcm/3.0.8_1/include/gdcm-3.0/gdcmjpeg/jpegint.h
```

So you probably want something like:

```
mex -compatibleArrayDims -I/usr/local/opt/jpeg/include ...
    -I/usr/local/opt/gdcm/include/gdcm-3.0/gdcmjpeg ...
    jpeg_write.c ...
    -L/usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gdcm/lib ...
    -ljpeg -lgdcmjpeg16
```

(I don't know if you actually want `-lgdcmjpeg8`, `-lgdcmjpeg12`, or `-lgdcmjpeg16`, or maybe something else. I'm just guessing here. Consult the GDCM documentation.)

Comment: thanks for your response Andrew.
I searched the file name and couldn't find it.
should I install the gdcm package to have it? or there are another packages also?

Comment: So I installed gdcm package and used jpegint.h from there. then I tried mex and it worked but with showing a warning. and I didn't care.
now when I run my project, Matlab shows me an error related to jpeg_write that I mentioned in here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64820620/matlab-error-writing-to-file-using-jpeg-write
can you please help me with that Andrew? I will appreciate it.